# Rails Gem Gattica :uninitialized constant Gattica::Auth::VERSION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics, rubygems

I am trying to access the Google Analytics data in my RoR project and I am using gem Gattica. I tried the basic code that is mentioned in the documentations that is

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'gattica'

gs = Gattica.new({:email => 'myemail', :password => 'mypassword', :timeout => 500})
    accounts = gs.accounts
    puts accounts
```

when I try to run the above code I am getting the following error

> uninitialized constant Gattica::Auth::VERSION (NameError)

I found that this repository is not updated from past few years. Should I continue using it and Any suggestions what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time on google about gem gattica I found that there is an updated repo for  the gem is available on github.

```
gem "gattica", "0.6.2", :git => "https://github.com/chrisle/gattica.git"
```

Just updated the gemfile and my issue was fixed.
Still wondering why it's not updated on http://rubygems.org/gems/gattica. They still have 0.4.3 when 0.6.2 is available

Answer (score 0):

This `VERSION` constant is used to identify `Gattica` within Google **only** (see https://github.com/activenetwork/gattica/blob/master/lib/gattica/auth.rb).

To quickly avoid the problem you can simply set it before call to constructor:

```
Gattica::Auth::VERSION=1
gs = Gattica.new …
```

But please stay noticed that `Gattica` was not being developed for 5 years so expect further problems (especially with authentication.)

Hop it helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply but still facing the same issue. And what you suggest should I use  Gattica or try any other gem.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue regarding how `Gattica` will deal with current Google APIs.

Comment: I am following this http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/google-analytics-data-export-api-with-rubygattica for the moment but still facing the same issue